# How do I use a list of Dates from .txt as input in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, cdo-climate

I'm trying to extract dates from a .nc file and I wanted to write a script to automate the process by using a .txt file, the data looks like this:

```
1995 04 05  
1995 06 12  
1995 06 30  
1995 07 16  
1995 07 19  
1995 07 20  
1995 07 28  
1996 03 09  
1996 04 25  
1996 08 13
```

I want to assign a variable for years, months and days separately e.g. , so that It would take the date from each line as input it in a command like this:

```
cdo seltimestep,$DD "mon_$MM.nc" "/Desktop/2020/output/$YYYY-$MM-$DD.nc"
```

I previously made a script similar to this but I had to input each date manually.

Comment: What you are making sounds like a program, not a script. Is this script required to be bash by your manager? If not, try Python and you'll save lot's of headaches with timestamps.

Comment: Not really, It's just that I have no experience with python as opposed to bash.

Answer (score 3):

You can read input file line by line and then use bash array to split the dates.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  dateArray=( $line )
  echo "YYYY: ${dateArray[0]}, MM: ${dateArray[1]}, DD: ${dateArray[2]}"
done < input.file
```

Comment: I like this answer, nice one.

Comment: You don't need an array for this, and `dateArray=( $line )` is bad practice. Instead do: `while read -r year month day _; printf 'YYYY: %04d, MM: %02d, DD: %02d\n' $((10#year)) $((10#month)) $((10#day)); done <input.file`

Comment: @LéaGris is my new favorite person.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```sh
awk '{printf("YYYY: %04d, MM: %02d, DD: %02d\n", $1, $2, $3)}' input.txt
```

The actual awk program is very straightforward, printing formatted fields of each record line:

```
{
  printf("YYYY: %04d, MM: %02d, DD: %02d\n", $1, $2, $3)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Read` can create all needed vars from line at once

```
while read  -r   year         month       day; do
    echo "Year: $year Month: $month Day: $day"
done < file
```